# R: floor_date returns just the date and not the date and time

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a data and time vector that I want to round down to the nearest 20-minute period. It works fine when I use the *floor_date* from the package **lubridate** on parts of the vector, but when I apply it on the whole vector, I only get the dates (without the time) back. Can anyone explain why this happens, and advice how to fix it? This is an example:

Just applying it on the first part of the vector returns what I expect:

```
> floor_date(as.POSIXct(test[1:20]), unit = "20 mins")
 [1] "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET"
 [5] "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET"
 [9] "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET"
[13] "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET"
[17] "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET" "2003-02-04 04:40:00 CET"
```

Performing it on the whole vector gives just the date:

```
> head(floor_date(as.POSIXct(test), unit = "20 mins"), 20)
 [1] "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET"
 [7] "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET"
[13] "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET"
[19] "2003-02-04 CET" "2003-02-04 CET"
```

It is a rather long vector (n = 8827411), but I would not think that should really matter?

When I try to investigate this, it seems that for some reason the *as.POSIXct* returns just a date object for some values, but not for most of the values. Why is this? E.g. When I look at these two values, that really look identical to me:

```
> test[8717005]
[1] "2020-03-29 02:58:32.200"
> test[8718005]
[1] "2020-03-29 04:55:01.400"
```

One of them is returned as date and time - the other only as date. Why is that?

```
> as.POSIXct(test[8717005])
[1] "2020-03-29 CET"
> as.POSIXct(test[8718005])
[1] "2020-03-29 04:55:01 CEST"
```

or

```
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 02:58:32.200")
[1] "2020-03-29 CET"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 04:55:01.400")
[1] "2020-03-29 04:55:01 CEST"
```

So, I guess the problem is not with the floor_date, but with the *as.POSIXct*. But I don't understand why it does not return the same on two values that seems exactly the same. Fooling around with this a bit, it seems it does not like *2* on this particular date?? But the date before and after works fine. And any other hours than 2 works fine also for this date.

```
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 01:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 01:00:00 CET"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 02:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 CET"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 03:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 03:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 04:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 04:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 05:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 05:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 06:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 06:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 07:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 07:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 08:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 08:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 09:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 09:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 10:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 10:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 11:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 11:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 12:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 12:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-29 02:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-29 CET"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-30 02:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-30 02:00:00 CEST"
> as.POSIXct("2020-03-28 02:00:00")
[1] "2020-03-28 02:00:00 CET"
```

Can anyone understand what is special about this particular hour on this particular date?? Why do I get this, and how can I fix it?? (This was just one example I found in the rather long vector - there were a couple of other instances where the *as.POSIXct* returned only the date, but in all cases, the format was exactly the same as the cases where both time and date was returned)

Comment: In your last code block with all the tests, notice your time zones. You are experimenting around the border of CET and CEST - right when the daylight savings time change kicks in. `"2020-03-29 02:00:00"` doesn't exist in the time zone because it is skipped by daylight savings time transition. I would suggest making sure your time zone is set to whenever this data was collected, which seems to be a time zone (like UTC) that doesn't use daylight savings time. (Or at least that switched to summer time on a different date.)

Comment: In addition to the comment above, you will not get time back when the time is at midnight. Lubricate ignores printing that,yet you can still work with the date as a date time object

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this seems indeed to have been the problem. Adding tz = "gmt" solves the issue.